# How can I set properties of external QML which is loaded via Loader

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML loaded via Loader & registered as .rcc file via registerResource(), I want to change some properties, ex. name : "LoadedQml".
How can I do it?

Comment: did you try to acces `Loader.item` which contains your loaded QML file as an `QtObject` ??? and later you can access your loaded QML file  [property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) `name`

Comment: Please provide [mcve] instead of explainig it.